# ngOnchanges and DoCheck in angular

Tags: angular, angular-lifecycle-hooks, ngonchanges, angular2-docheck

When study the difference between ngOnChanges and DoCheck in Angular, I see something I cant explain and need your help.

Basically, I understand that ngOnChanges can't recognize the change of array or object and DoCheck can. I created the stackblitz here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-sbyzya?file=src/app/app.component.html

In app.component.html

- If you comment line 2, so only component which ngOnChanges run, the data **didn't sort** when click add or edit. It 's right because OnChange can't detect the change of array @Input.

```
<data-table-onchange [data]="numbers"></data-table-onchange>
<!-- <data-table-docheck [data]="numbers"></data-table-docheck> -->
```

- If you comment line 1, so only component which DoCheck run, the data **sort** when click add or edit. It 's right because DoCheck can detect the change of array @Input.

```
<!--<data-table-onchange [data]="numbers"></data-table-onchange> -->
 <data-table-docheck [data]="numbers"></data-table-docheck>
```

- But if you let both child component run, when click add or edit, data in both child component is sorted. It seems weird to me because I dont understand why the DataTableOnchangeComponent can run sort function. I put sort in ngOnChanges, ngOnChanges didn't trigger when click add or edit, but somehow the data still get sorted.

```
<data-table-onchange [data]="numbers"></data-table-onchange>
<data-table-docheck [data]="numbers"></data-table-docheck>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason both the tables are sorting the numbers, when you uncomment both the lines is because, when the DoCheck initiates the sorting, the  **numbers** array is actually getting sorted, and it's the **same array** that shows up in both the components. Javascript's Pass By Reference in play.

To see the difference, try setting 2 different arrays to both the component, and you should see that the array in the OnChanges component does not sort.

```
<data-table-onchange [data]="numbers"></data-table-onchange>
<data-table-docheck [data]="numbers2"></data-table-docheck>
```

in TS

```
public numbers: number[] = [5, 69, 9];
public numbers2: number[] = [5, 69, 9];

public add(): void {
  const random: number = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
  this.numbers.push(random);
  this.numbers2.push(random);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I totally forgot about pass by reference :D